# STM32: Difference between HAL_xxx_Init() and HAL_xxx_MspInit()

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, programming, hal-library, stm32f3

When using the HAL (Hardware Abstraction Library) for any of the STM32 micro controllers:

For a given peripheral, why do you have to call an **HAL_...*init()*** , as well as a **HAL..._MspInit()** - why are several 'inits' separated?

Answer (score 5):

The ST User Manual [UM1725 - Description of STM32F4 HAL and LL drivers](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/2f/71/ba/b8/75/54/47/cf/DM00105879.pdf/files/DM00105879.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105879.pdf), see pages 61 - 63, gives an explanation:

> The *peripheral initialization* is done through **HAL_PPP_Init()** while
>   the *hardware resources initialization* used by a peripheral (**PPP**) is performed during this initialization by calling **MSP** callback function **HAL_PPP_MspInit()**.
>   The **MspInit** callback performs the low-level initialization related to the different additional hardware resources: RCC, GPIO, NVIC and DMA.

(MSP: **M**CU **S**upport **P**ackage)

and

2.12.2 **HAL global initialization:**

> **HAL_Init():**  this function must be called at application startup to
>   - initialize data/instruction cache and pre-fetch queue
>   -  set SysTick timer to generate an interrupt each 1ms (based on HSI clock) with the lowest priority
>   - set priority grouping to 4 preemption bits
>   - call **HAL_MspInit()** user callback function to perform system level initializations (Clock, GPIOs, DMA, interrupts). **HAL_MspInit()** is defined as “weak” empty
>   function in the HAL drivers.